# Making text field taggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I'm new to JavaScript and new to jQuery plugin development. My plugin is really easy I just want to taggify a `<ul>`

```
    (function($) {
        var allTags;
        $.fn.taggify = function(options) {
            allTags = this;
            _create(allTags);
            return this;
        };  

        function _create(theElement) {
            var inputWrapper = $('<li></li>');
            var input = $('<input></input>');
            input.attr('type', 'text');
            input.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
            input.css('border', 'none');
            input.css('outline', 'none');
            inputWrapper.html(input)

            allTags.append(inputWrapper);
            _event(input);
        }

        function _event(theText) {
            theText.keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode === 13) {
                    var aTag = $('<li></li>');
                    aTag.addClass('tag-choice');

                    var aSpan = $('<span></span>');
                    aSpan.addClass('tag-label');

                    var tagText= theText.val();
                    aSpan.html(tagText);
                    aTag.html(aSpan);

                allTags.prepend(aTag);
                theText.val('');
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look too shabby! A few comments.

- Declaring but then not using `options` made me stumble. If you don't have any options, don't make a parameter called options.
- In my opinion there's not much point in separating `_create` and `_event` into two separate functions. If you do, you should rename `_event` so that it's more like a function name. Functions should be named such that they start with a verb; try something like `_attachListener`.
- It's fine to use a closure-scope variable, but you're kind of half-using it. If you combine your two functions, you'll be able to get rid of it entirely.
- `_create` isn't using its `theElement` parameter.
- You should take advantage of method chaining when creating `input`. Also, consider naming jQuery variables with a leading `$` to make it very explicit what type they are.
- The [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function does not take a `jQuery` object as a valid parameter; it takes either an `htmlString` or a `function`. Instead you should use `inputWrapper.append(input);`.
- In fact, rather than creating an `inputWrapper` at all, use the [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.
- Do you really want to use `aSpan.html(tagText);`, or do you want to use `.text()`? This depends on your use case but usually people will expect the behaviour of `.text()` (e.g. not having to escape their angle brackets).
- For consistency, either name them both `anInput` and `aSpan` or drop the prefix.
- Note that using function chaining, you can in fact completely eliminate the need for having any variables at all, if you prefer.

Here's my proposed rewrite:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.taggify = function(options) {
    create(this);
    return this;
  };

  function create($theElement) {
    var $input = $('<input></input>')
      .attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
      .css('border', 'none')
      .css('outline', 'none')
      .wrap('<li></li>');

    $input.on('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var tagText = $input.val();
        var $span = $('<span class="tag-label"></span>');

        $span.text(tagText).wrap('<li class="tag-choice"></li>');
        $theElement.prepend($span.parent());
        $input.val('');
      }
    });

    $theElement.append($input.parent());
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('ul').taggify();
});
```

```css
ul {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But it looks like the wrap method doesn't work

Comment: @toy Sorry about that. Try it out now! :-)